# При создании массива из файла выбросить знаки препинания

Tags: intellij-idea, scala

Как при создании массива сделать так, чтобы считывался только текст без знаков препинаний? Вот код:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("hello.txt")
    val lines = try source.mkString finally source.close()

    val arr: Array[String] = lines.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод **split** принимает **регулярное выражение**. В вашем примере он просто избавляется от пробелов. Можно также составить регулярное выражение, которое избавит ваши выходные данные и от знаков препинания.

Пример:

```
val str = "Hello, World! How are you?"
val arr: Array[String] = str.split("""[\W\n]+""")
```

На выходе в массиве будут элементы:

```
Hello
World
How
are
you
```

Здесь в регулярке **"""[\W\n]+"""** я указал, что делить строку необходимо там, где попадётся **\W** (любой символ, кроме цифры, буквы или знака подчеркивания) или **\n** (перевод строки) при одном или более вхождений (**+**). Тройные кавычки используются для записи неинтерпретируемых строк (не обрабатывает обратные слеши, чтобы лишний раз их не экранировать).

Более подробно про регулярные выражения можно почитать в литературе или на ресурсах интернета.